# Invalid connection using C# on windows ce sqlconnection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am creating a Smart Device project using `VS2008` for a `WIndows CE 6.0` device with `.Net Compact Framework 3.5`

Here is my code:

```
        string queryString = "SELECT id, name, insert_date, activity FROM dbo.[my Table]";
        StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dba;Initial Catalog=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usern;Password=paswd"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                //command.Connection.Open();
                //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
                {
                    errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                        "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                        "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                        "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                        "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Mind that usernames ant table names are  changed but I am getting the following errors on `command.Connection.Open();`

```
Index #0
Message: Invalid connection.
LineNumber: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure: ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).
```

Why and how to fix it? The device easly pings the server machine if that is useful.

Comment: Anybody got the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

at place of command.Connection.Open();
use connection.open()
and after execute query 
close the connection...

Comment: tried it but the problem persists on the windows CE device though if I create a Windows Forms application it is ok.(both the computer and the Smart Device is in the same network)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, open the connection prior to creating the command object, you will not need to close the connection because it is inside the using{}